# how to compute a coordinate that forms a square around a GPS point given the max perimeter of square?

Tags: gps, geospatial, distance, latitude-longitude, geosphere

So the goal is that, when given a `(lat, lng)` point, which should form the center of square, and the max perimeter of the square in (in miles, km, etc.), output out:

```
[ (min_lat, min_lng), (max_lat, max_lng) ]
```

Comment: There are many open source spatial libraries available, most of them should do this with a single line. Which language do you use? Note, a perfect square does not exist on a sphere.

Comment: I use node, javascript. I am aware that it is approximation, which is good enough.

Comment: Then have a look at https://turfjs.org/docs/